# Error en SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data con ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Cuando agrego desde mi formulario por medio de una función, me envía el mensaje de

> Error.JSON.parse...

Tengo el siguiente script en Carpeta: `Script->JS->miscript.js`

```
var data = {
    id_cliente: cliente,
    id_asesor: asesor,
    codigo_operacion: codigo_opera,
    secuencia: secuencia,
    monto_solicitado: monto_solicitado,
    tipo_garantia: garantia,
    fecha_validacion_checklist: fecha,
    numero_integrantes: integrantes,
    tipo_check_list: tipo_check,
    status: status
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/CheckList/InsertDatos",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Y en mi Controller el metodo el cual recibo

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult InsertDatos(CHECK_LIST chl)
    {

        using (DB_CEAEntities db = new DB_CEAEntities())
        {

            var cl = new CHECK_LIST()
            {
                id_cliente = chl.id_cliente,
                id_asesor = chl.id_asesor,
                codigo_operacion = chl.codigo_operacion,
                secuencia = chl.secuencia,
                monto_solicitado = chl.monto_solicitado,
                tipo_garantia = chl.tipo_garantia,
                fecha_validacion_checklist = chl.fecha_validacion_checklist,
                numero_integrantes = chl.numero_integrantes,
                tipo_check_list = chl.tipo_check_list,
                status = chl.status
            };

            db.CHECK_LIST.Add(cl);

            //db..add(cat);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json("Ok");
    }
```

Alguien podría decirme mi error,lo mismo ocurre cuando realizo una consulta.

Comment: De donde obtienes los valores que asignas en `var data`?, `cliente`, `asesor`, `codigo_opera`, etc. Según indicas, ese javascript lo tienes en un archivo independiente, cómo obtienes los valores?

Comment: de los valores del input, los obtengo por Jquery 
let cliente = $("#cliente").val();
Lo tengo en la carpeta Script y hace el llamado solo un boton al nombre de la funcion, segun mi console.log() me trae todos los datos

Comment: Es correcto. Pues edita la pregunta, e indica el código donde asignas los valores a las variables con jQuery. Y también la clase de Modelo `chl`.

Comment: Otra cosa, estás entrando a la Acción `InsertDatos()` o ni si quiera llega ahí?. Veo que tienes un `[Authorize]`

Comment: Oye, me funciono a la perfección el problema era el [Authorize], soy nuevo aun no puedo darte como resuelta, puedes postearla, mil gracias amigo

Comment: Estupendo!. me alegro te haya funcionado. He agregado la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Envia la función ajax de la siguiente forma

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/CheckList/InsertDatos",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

El método `stringify()` convierte tu objeto a JSON. Espero que te sirva saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La construcción del `var data`, parece correcto según tus comentarios.

Por otra parte, tienes un `[Authorize]` en tu Acción `InsertDatos(CHECK_LIST chl)` y no veo que estés comprobando usuario autenticados. Elimina el `[Authorize]` y debería funcionar:

```
// [Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InsertDatos(CHECK_LIST chl)
{
     //...
}
```